# WordPress custom post loop - echo variable once

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop that gets all the posts that are "custom_post". It works perfectly - apart from that when I echo a variable it duplicates the variable when there are more than one post.

Its hard to explain - but basically if I have one post it works perfectly. I get a Div with the class name that is assigned to that custom post.

When I add another post - again that works, but displays two divs with the second post. I would imagine that it has something to do with echo $variable in the loop.

Any ideas? Thanks

**EDIT**

CODE:

```
function display_css() {

    $ids = array();
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_post');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
array_push( $ids, get_the_ID() );
endwhile;
foreach (array_unique($ids) as $key => $value) {
$check_select_modules = $titan->getOption( 'selec_modules', $value );
if ( "accordianmodule" == $check_select_modules) {
include(DE_DB_PATH . '/lib/modules/accordian.php');
}
elseif ( "textmodule" == $check_select_modules) {
include(DE_DB_PATH . '/lib/modules/text.php');
}
else {
}
}

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'display_css', 15 );
```

Then in one of the php scripts it has

```
$css_accordian .= '<style id="css-'.$accordian_module_heading_css_class_display.'">';
echo $css_accordian;
```

I get the variable $accordian_module...... further up the script.

Comment: In other words `.=` means `append`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you miss a quote here:

```
$variable .= '<div class"'.$classname.;">;
```

should be:

```
$variable .= '<div class"'.$classname.'">';
```

Suggestion:

```
$ids = array();
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_post');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post(); 
        array_push($ids, get_the_ID());
    }  
}
```

However.. instead of using a foreach to loop through all the ID's for a second time, why you not echo a div in side the loop above, like this:

```
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post(); 
    echo '<div class="'.$classname.'">' . the_ID() . '</div>';
   }  
 }
```

Or do you want one div where all the posts are shown?

Comment: I want one div per post.

Comment: Tried this and still produces more than one. It might be something else. I have a if statement in the loop and if it matches I include another php script that echoes the classname. Could this be it?

Comment: Can you show me where you declare $classname? The second while loop I gave you really prints only one div for each post. So something else is going on.

Comment: I have done an edit for you to see - maybe this will help>?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $classname is not being set in that piece of code you have copied here. I'm guessing it gets assigned some value before this code?
I recommend set the classname into the $ids array (though you should call that something else then) during the while loop. something like this, though "$post->classname" probably won't work, you'll have to figure out where to get classname from.

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  $ids[get_the_ID()] = $post->classname;
endwhile;
```

Then in the for loop, the $value will contain your classname, so you can do this:

```
foreach (array_unique($ids) as $key => $value) {
  $variable ='<div class"'.$value.;">;
  echo $variable;
}
```

Comment: I see where you are going but this wont work as I have so many fields to get from the post. I was just using classname as one example.

Comment: You can put another array into the array, of course:

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      $ids[get_the_ID()] = array(
        "classname" => $post->classname,
        "nextvar" => "whatever");
    endwhile;

and then in your for loop:

$variable ='<div class"'.$value["classname].;">;